# Passing Query string from SharePoint site to app part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to pass Query string from sharepoint page to an app part.
I have followed

https://prasantabarik.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/pass-querystring-value-from-sharepoint-page-to-app-partclient-web-part/

Modified element.xml..[image]

and in script editor I have added

```
<script>
  var arrFrames = document.getElementsByTagName(“iframe”);
  for(i = 0; i< arrFrames.length; i++)
  {
    var iFrame=arrFrames[i];
    var clientID=”QueryStringIDValue”;
    if(iFrame.src.indexOf(clientID) != -1)
    {
      alert();
      var queryStringValue=getQuerystring(‘QueryStringID’);
      if(queryStringValue != null)
      {
        iFrame.src=iFrame.src.replace(clientID,queryStringValue);
      }
    }
  }  

  function getQuerystring(key)    
  {
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/,”\\\[“).replace(/[\]]/,”\\\]”);
    var regex = new RegExp(“[\\?&]”+key+”=([^&#]*)”);
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(qs == null)
      return null;
    else
      return qs[1];
  }
</script>
```

So what do i need to do next to use that query string value in my app part?

Comment: What error are you getting? The quotes are not well formed here. Try forming them correctly.

Comment: M not getting any error but if I have to pass the current page url to the app part, what do I need to do next?

Comment: For current page url, you can use document.referrer which you've already used in the previous question that you asked.